# What would happen if somebody knew how to make the Asterix's & Obelix's magic potion work nowadays?

Tags: magic

My friend came up with this in a discussion, and we didn't get anywhere debating about this (I'm not the magic-world-ish type), so I thought I'd ask it:

In the world of [Asterix, Obelix and their village](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix_the_Gaul), the druid they have can brew a magical potion, giving its drinker (almost) unlimited power and strength, and most probably even invincibility. That means that such a potion would not only give strength harden its drinker's bones, muscles and skin, and would also make the drinker weigh much more, so they don't get propelled back when they punch somebody. Also, it would somehow magically negate all the attacks, so the people don't die, and in most cases don't even lose consciousness (thanks to @Kaël in the comments)

What global economic changes would happen if somebody nowadays knew how to make it?

Comment: You forgot a little thing, it also almost negates the attack power of the punches, since in that comics, roman soldiers never dies from the big blows they're taking, even though a single punch from Obélix can crunch metal :p

Comment: @Kaël Ah, yeah... or it makes everything in contact the drinker also super-powered, but just for a few milliseconds - if it makes them more heavy, why doesn't the floor break under them? :)

Comment: @Kaël: That's most likely censorship of violence. The authors do reference this as being an issue, by drawing floral curtains over carnage.

Comment: This is magical strength and invincibility. So, of course, it doesn't hurt when they hit somebody, simply propel them great distances. Magically it cancels action & reaction because that would be inconvenient. Forget about hardening bones & increasing mass. That's just science (boy! it pains me to write that), this is magic.

Comment: *What would happen?* Are you interested in the effects on the global oil prices? How the next election in Belgium would turn out? Or how it would affect the future of standing stone design? I'm sorry, but this is too broad. Please try to narrow your question down to the aspects of life you are interested in.

Comment: @Philipp I edited; it now says `What are the **most important thinks that would happen** if somebody nowadays knew how to make it?`

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek That doesn't narrow it down at all, unless you also define what aspects you consider important.

Comment: @Philipp What about this: `What are the most important global economic, politic and safety changes that would happen if somebody nowadays knew how to make it?`

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek When you pick *one* of these I might retract my close-vote.

Comment: @Philipp So I should ask 3 different questions? I think leaving it like this is better. Also, people use "common sense" and won't answer that this would make the mother of the French president happy or whatelse.

Comment: @Philipp, also, these themes greatly overlap.

Comment: OP, they have closed your question. Please consider editing your question  as suggested so that it can be reopened.

Answer (score 6):

#### It would be quite strictly controlled by governments

This is something that would make maintaining law and order much more difficult. It's much easier to break into secure buildings (you just rip open iron doors, etc.) It's much easier to injure or kill people. (Even by accident, remember how many people Obelix has taken out due to his clumsiness.) You can steal a car by lifting it up and carrying it away. It would be technically possible to get on a flight and kill everybody (including yourself) by punching holes through the windows/fuselage. Those are just a few of countless examples.

Governments would argue that this potion is too dangerous in the hands of criminals and terrorists, so they would therefore want to strictly control it. Legions of dogs would be trained to sniff for it, and anyone found to be in illegal possession of it would be shot with tranquilizer darts (or something like that) and punished very severely.

Most governments would make this a banned or illegal substance. It would be given a similar treatment to that of heroin, only much more severe.

Of course, the governments themselves would use it for their armed forces, some police etc.

There may be some exceptions where civilians would be able to use it, but it would be rare and it would be strictly controlled. You'd need a license, and you'd only be able to get that if there was a very good reason, like some task you needed to perform. Abusing the license would be punished very severely.

Of course, some outlaws, etc. would still manufacture, use and distribute it, but it would be similarly difficult and risky to do as other criminal activities are today (smuggling of drugs/weapons, human trafficking, etc.)

Or actually,  perhaps it would be *much more* difficult, as this potion would be a worse *direct threat* to governments than those other things are. Thus,  they may put more severe efforts into controlling it.

We know [some of the ingredients](http://asterix.wikia.com/wiki/Magic_potion) of the potion. The main difficulty with controlling the potion is that people can cook it at home from readily available ingredients. (This is similar to crystal meth.) However, it's extremely important for governments to control the potion. So, they may consider banning one or more of the ingredients.

Comment: *it would be similarly difficult and risky to do as other criminal activities are today (smuggling of drugs/weapons, human trafficking, etc.)* ...so... not difficult at all?

Comment: @Philipp Depends on what you mean. Would you want to bring five kilos of heroin from Afghanistan to NY? (Ignoring ethical considerations, regarding risk/difficulty.)

Comment: No, because most heroin comes into the United States from Mexico. The opiates from Afghanistan mostly go to Europe and India. The drug cartels don't seem to consider it risky at all. They import *tons* (literally) of heroin into the US every year.

Comment: @Philipp Well, [90% of the world's heroin comes from Afghanistan](http://www.npr.org/2016/07/06/484894669/afghan-governor-wants-government-to-control-poppy-crop). I don't dispute your points on heroin,  though. However,  this discussion we have now started is quite irrelevant. I believe we agree on the basic idea that dealing with this illegal substance will be somewhat dangerous and risky, though still possible for determined people. To *what degree* it will be dangerous and risky is obviously a matter of opinion.

Comment: However, I do believe this potion will be seen as a *much* bigger threat than what heroin currently is. Therefore,  governments will make a much more severe effort to control it. @Philipp

Comment: You have convinced me! I repent of my evil ways. I confess I was bribed by the Getafix Corporation to promote their evil potion. Once they bought up all of Big Pharma, nothing could stand in their way. Ban lobsters now before it is too late. Excuse me while I go into hiding just in case they try to rub me out.

Comment: @a4android Nice try. There is already a warrant for your arrest.

Answer (score 2):

The Getafix magic potion, if it could made today, would make a fortune. There are endless market opportunities. Athletes, the forces of law and order, the armed forces, anybody who has sand kicked in their face, wives who have nasty husbands, children with unpleasant parents, criminals (now there's a lucrative market niche), and even the sick and dying who are in dire need of a lift to get them moving.

Think of the boon this will bring to the home handyman market. No more nasty accidents around the weekend when people are renovating or fixing things around the house. Being invincible would protect them from harm. Being super-strong would make those home handy jobs easy.

Basically anybody with money and with intent to do something that needs strength and invincibility will pay to have a belt.

This would be a magnificent benefit to all humanity. The makers of Getafix, potion to the gods, would suffer the dreadful fate of dying extremely rich and testing to its absolute limits the phrase about whether money can buy happiness.

Comment: ...if Getafix is smart enough to secure the patent rights and keep them save from the pharma companies who will try to trick him out of them.

Comment: There's more than enough money made selling the magic potion. Our modern Getafix and Big Pharma can afford to cooperate to their mutual financial benefit. Their main problem might be that traditional herbal remedies can be difficult to patent. Existing art, and all that other intellectual property hoo-ha. There's oodles of moolah to be made, they can easily share.

Comment: Why would big pharma share with him when they can screw him over and take all of it?

Comment: Commonsense & fear of scrutiny of their business affairs. The Getafix potion would attract attention in the modern world. Anyone claiming they had been screwed by Big Pharma will bring the regulators, the legislators, & taxation authorities breathing down their neck and going through their records. They would want to avoid that, as sense dictates. Now rubbing him out, that's different. So tempting!

Comment: What if it went wrong?

Comment: Big pharma companies employ whole armies of lawyers and lobbyists.The regulators, legislators and taxation authorities are no threat to them. This is a battle Getafix has no chance of winning.

Comment: Went wrong? The potion or rubbing him out? if it's rubbing him out, we're back to the sense of sharing what is a proverbial gold mine. Money enough for everyone involved. Now if the potion went wrong, then there will be a lot of legal action. That's fine! Now the lawyers can win too.

Comment: @Philipp For every entrenched power either economic or political or both there is a tipping point which even they cannot oppose. I suspect a scandal around the Getafix potion would be that tipping point for Big Pharma. The whole electorate would be aroused by the issue. It would be a 24 carat bandwagon opportunity for shafting Big Pharma. Corporate executives aren't complete morons, although they do do good imitations of it, they would realise this too. They can settle out of court too.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this potion will be included on the list of banned doping substances for athletes... lol.